# echo HTML in PHP in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, echo

im trying to build a blogsite with wordpress and im trying to show a clickable picture with a link.

```
            <?php 
            $counter = get_posts();
            $i = 0;
            while ($i < count($counter)) {
                $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1,'offset' => $i );
                $i = $i + 3;
                $lastposts = get_posts( $args );
                foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
                setup_postdata( $post );
                $permalink = the_permalink();
                $thumbnail = the_post_thumbnail_url();
                echo '<a href="'.$permalink.'"><img src="' . $thumbnail . '"> </img></a>';
                /*the_post_thumbnail();*/
                endforeach; 
                wp_reset_postdata();
            }

           ?>
```

I think the echo does not work :/
The result is this:

```html
<div class="col span_1_of_3">
  This is column 1 http://lena.sbstn.net/2017/04/14/ein-neuer-post/http://lena.sbstn.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/22.jpg
  <a href=""> <img src=""> </a>http://lena.sbstn.net/2017/01/29/new-york-cheesecake/http://lena.sbstn.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/image2-525x700.jpg
  <a href=""> <img src=""> </a>
</div>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: you need to put the actual output here, not the rendered html on your screen.

Comment: @TurtleTread i edited the question :) Thanks! (But I do not understand the output..)

Comment: see how to use the functions here. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink. also https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/ if you like to get a return value instead of directly echoing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_post_thumbnail_url()` already prints the url.

Use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` instead.

Again for permalink, use `get_the_permalink()` instead of `the_permalink()`.

As you can see in your update, it directly prints the values instead of assigning into the variables.

If you want to use `the_permalink()` & `the_post_thumbnail_url()` then use directly in the location instead of assigning into a variable.